# Java Create new file automatically depend on size

Tags: java

Trying to Write java Code to write ".dat" File.. While wring check size as well.. every 200 KB create new ".dat" continue to write file. Is there any way that i can do that..

when file more than 200KB and create new one filename like this

```
1st file name.. 1_filename 
2nd file name.. 2_filename
3rd file name.. 3_filename........
```

or if file create only one file means less than 200KB than

Filenamd.. filename as in code..

I wrote code to write files but.. its only writing 2 files.. and that's not right way to do it..

Here is my code..

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class xmlfile1filebytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File folder = new File ("07072013");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        System.out.println("There are " + listOfFiles.length + " files"); 
        String filesin;

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy[HH.mm.ss]")
        .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(timeStamp);

        BufferedWriter xmlfile = null;
        BufferedWriter datfile = null;

        String outxmlfile = ("07072013\\" + timeStamp + ".xml");
        xmlfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outxmlfile));

        String outdatfile = ("07072013\\" + timeStamp + ".dat");
        datfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outdatfile));

        int offset = 0;
        int size = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            File f = listOfFiles[i];
            // System.out.println(i + " " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            if (f.isFile()) {
                filesin = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                if (filesin.endsWith("pdf")) {
                    Path aPath = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
                    System.out.println(filesin);
                    byte[] actualBytes = Files.readAllBytes(aPath);
                    size = actualBytes.length;
                    xmlfile.append((i + 1) + ")" + " File = " + filesin + ", Offset = " + offset + ", Size = " + size + "\n");

                    offset = offset + size;
                    xmlfile.newLine();

                    String s = new String(actualBytes);

                    datfile.append(s);
                    datfile.newLine();

                    File datfileinfolder = new File ("07072013\\" + timeStamp + ".dat");

                    long datfilesize = datfileinfolder.length();
                    long datfilesizeinkb = datfilesize /1024;

                    System.out.println(datfilesizeinkb);

                    if (datfilesizeinkb >= 200) {
                        datfile.close();

                        BufferedWriter datfile1 = null;
                        String outdatfile1 = ("07072013\\" + "1_"+ timeStamp + ".dat");
                        datfile1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outdatfile1));

                        String s1 = new String(actualBytes);
                        datfile1.append(s1);
                        datfile1.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        xmlfile.close();
    }
}
```

And I get error when write file more than 400 KB..

ERROR:

```
    There are 10 files
07-09-2013[16.03.00]
1192970_eBill_20130709.pdf
96
1321470_eBill_20130709.pdf
208
1724897_eBill_20130709.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Unknown Source)
    at xmlfile1filebytes.main(xmlfile1filebytes.java:65)
```

Comment: You need to show us which line causes the exception, xmlfile1filebytes.java:65. Also, I've edited your question to remove some of the unnecessary begging.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a separate class whose only job it is to create files (in sequence), write data to the file, keep an eye on the size, and close / open files as needed. This will make your code more organized - you will be able to see your mistakes more clearly. The class would have the following methods:

```
setMax(maxVal)                 - set the maximum file size (default 400k)
setRoot(rootPath)              - folder where files will be created
setName(rootName)              - "format string" used to generate file names 
                                 (e.g. "myFile%03d.dat")
writeData(dataSize, dataBlock) - write data. If no file open, open it. 
                                 If file too big, split it.  
closeFile()                    - flush buffers, close the last file.
                                 Could be part of the destructor
currentFile()                  - returns name of current file (for debug)
currentSize()                  - returns current file size (for debug)
```

If you can figure out how to write this class you will solve your initial problem and have something you can re-use at the same time.

If you want to stay with (mostly) the code structure you already have, then your fix is to remove your current line 85.

```
     83:         String s1 = new String(actualBytes);
     84:         datfile1.append(s1);
     85:         datfile1.close();  <<<<<<<<<<< remove this line
     86:      }
```

Once you have closed the file, your next attempt to write to it will fail - and that's the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You do `datfile.close()`, and on the next iteration through the for loop you `.append()` to it. You'll have to initialize (i.e. open) your `datfile` *inside* the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Okay looks like a book keeping issue.

Here is how it should look like

```
    .
    .
    . 
    long datfilesize = datfileinfolder.length();;
    final int BLOCK_SIZE = 200 * 1024;
    for (int curBlock = 0; curBlock < actualBytes.length; curBlock += BLOCK_SIZE) {
        String toWrite = new String(
            Arrays.copyOfRange(actualBytes, curBlock, Math.min(curBlock + BLOCK_SIZE, actualBytes.length)
        );
        String suffix = "";
        if (curBlock > 0) {
            //append underscores other file information and then perform writes
            suffix =  String.valueOf(curBlock /  BLOCK_SIZE);
        }    

        //Your code more or less
        BufferedWriter datfile1 = null;
        String outdatfile1 = ("07072013\\" + suffix + timeStamp + ".dat");
        datfile1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outdatfile1));


        datfile1.append(toWrite);
        datfile1.close(); 
    }
```

Edit: Does this make more sense ?

Here's the gist. The for loop iterates in block size of BLOCK_SIZE(200 KB). If file size is less than BLOCK_SIZE, you need not append any suffixes(See the **if block**). Else you append the **suffix** and then write to the file. The string is given by the local variable **toWrite**. You have read the whole file already and stored the bytes in **actualBytes**. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry man, I still didn't get it.. can you expain me more please.. help me.. thanks!!

Comment: See if _edit_ makes more sense.

Comment: Hey, I tried that, But it Still creating only 1 file with 439 KB.. it should created 3 file right?? Please help me!! Thanks in advanced!! I edit that code.. please check that.. and help me please!!

Comment: hey, Please help me.. please.. Thanks in advanced!! I really need your help please help me!! Thanks.. I comment the code that i used.. so please help me!!

Comment: Post your code after making the required changes.

Comment: I already comment my code.. acutally after i made changes.. look my list comment.. i already add your lines into code.. than i put it last check it.. its over there.. Please check it.. please replay me.. Thanks!!

Comment: I edit code.. please look at it.. please replay me.. Thanks!!

Comment: Modify the question, not my answer. I went through the edit. Remove all your file writing code after getting the actual bytes statement.

Comment: After getting the actual bytes statemnet?? remove all your file writing code.. what that mean?? please explain me.. little more please.. Thanks!!

Comment: This is my last comment. Edit question details.